# Is there a way to put different limitRange for different StorageClasses per namespace

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims, container-storage-interface

I am aware that we can put a **ResourceQuota** for a **StorageClass** per namespace which will limit the total amount of storage we can request per StorageClass per namespace. [Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#storage-resource-quota)

I am also aware that we can create a **LimitRange** to restrict the individual **PersistentVolumeClaim** to request storage in a defined range. [Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/limit-storage-consumption/#limitrange-to-limit-requests-for-storage)

But I want to have a different **LimitRange** for each **StorageClass** that I have defined. Is this possible..?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different limit range object for each project where you want to control resources.

**Sample limit range object for a container:**

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "LimitRange"
metadata:
  name: "resource-limits"
spec:
  limits:
    - type: "Container"
      max:
        cpu: "2"
        memory: "1Gi"
      min:
        cpu: "100m"
        memory: "4Mi"
      default:
        cpu: "300m"
        memory: "200Mi"
      defaultRequest:
        cpu: "200m"
        memory: "100Mi"
      maxLimitRequestRatio:
        cpu: "10"
```

You can create a single LimitRange object for any or all components as necessary. Refer to the [link](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/nodes/clusters/nodes-cluster-limit-ranges.html) for more information.